# Clear Validation Error Messages in modalpopup extender

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have asp.net ajax modal popup extender in which I have placed text boxes. The text boxes are validated and the validation error messages are shown.

There is a scenario where I need to clear the validation error messages.

When I save the modal popup without entering values, validation error messages appear. Now I close the modal popup clicking on cancel button.

Next time when I open the modal popup I see the same error messages. How could I clear just the validation error messages through jquery. I don't want to disable the validators but I only need to clear the error.

Comment: I tried the bellow code and then it worked. Cheers! 



$.each(Page_Validators, function (index, validator) {
                
                     $(validator).attr('style','display:none;')
               

            }
            );

Comment: @user1075000: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via [user10725000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1075000/user1075000), who really deserves the credit:

> I tried the bellow code and then it worked. Cheers!

```
$.each(Page_Validators, function (index, validator) { 
  $(validator).attr('style','display:none;') 
});
```